# How can i save input data to a differently named database column?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Basically, i have some code which validates my input (this is part of it):

```
    'r_email' => array(
        'exist' => array(
            'rule' => 'checkEmailExist',
            'message' => 'That email has already been used.'
        ),
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'The email field must not be blank.'
        ),
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'You must enter a valid email address'
        ),
    ),
```

So i have my validation rules in ok and they work when i do:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
```

My input form is as so (for above validation):

```
echo $this->Form->input('r_email', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Email Address',
    'div' => false
));
```

But the columns in my database have different names to the form inputs, therefore i assume the data will not save because it is not linked. I'm not sure how i can get around this and save data to my columns?

Comment: If you have different named inputs than your database column, then I presume you're not using the cake form helper. It will make your life much easier if you use the form helper, let it name the fields, then you won't have to worry about remapping your data to your model

Comment: I am using the form helper. But i have different validation rules for username, password, etc in the same Model. For instance, i want to check if a user exists already when registering, but when logging in i don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `name` attribute of your `input` by adding the specific key/value pair to the `options` array of `FormHelper::input`

```
echo $this->Form->input('r_email', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Email Address',
    'div' => false,
    'name' => 'data[User][field_in_database]'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $this->YourModelName->expectedfield=$this->data[ModelName][r_email]

here YourModelName will represent that which table you will insert this r_email and expectedFirled indicates that in which field you will insert r_email.

Got the answer if you can't you can reply for more information.